# SQL Server : Convert from VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Current Date Format: 12-18-2018-03:14:48

I want to convert to: 2018-12-18 03:14

Currently using SQL Server 2008

I'm using this code syntax:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(35) = '12-18-2018-03:14:48'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @input, 120)
```

Error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: The input for the `CONVERT()` call uses `MM-dd-yyy`, but the style 120 argument is `yyyy-MM-dd`. You need those to match. Find the style that matches your input here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your current datetime literal falls into any mask which SQL Server can recognize.  But we can try using `TRY_CONVERT` here, replacing the middle dash with a space:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(@input, 11, 1, ' ')) AS output;

18/12/2018 03:14:48
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server which does not support `TRY_CONVERT`, then we can try explicitly using `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(@input, 11, 1, ' ')) AS output;
```

Comment: I'm afraid `TRY_CONVERT` was introduced only in SQL Server **2012** and thus isn't available for someone on SQL Server 2008 ....

Comment: @marc_s `CONVERT` with the corrected datetime string seems to be working.